# superclass] construction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Briefly, I have a class implementation:

```
@implementation ClassB: ClassA
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And a category, in two variants:

**1:**

```
@implementation ClassA (ClassA_Category)
+(id) alloc {
    if ([self isEqual: [ClassA class]]) {
        return [ClassB alloc];
    } else {
        return [super alloc];
    }
}
@end
```

**2:**

```
@implementation ClassA (ClassA_Category)
+(id) alloc {
    return [[ClassB superclass] superclass] alloc];
}
@end
```

The question is about this simple initialization:

```
ClassA *aObj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
```

For the first category variant, `init` of `ClassB` is called, but for the second case - doesn't.

Why ? Does these two `alloc` constructions have the same meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ClassB superclass] superclass]` will be ClassA's superclass (probably NSObject — I'm going to assume so for the rest of this answer). So the second variant is specifically equivalent to `[NSObject alloc]`. This means the object that you send `init` to is just an NSObject, not a ClassA or a ClassB.

In the first variant, `[ClassB alloc]` executes ClassA's implementation (through inheritance), which calls `[super alloc]` in cases where the class is not ClassA (which ClassB isn't), which executes the default implementation of `alloc`. This allocates a ClassB, which is then sent `init`.

I think your confusion is caused by the assumption that `[[self superclass] theCurrentMethod]` is equivalent to `[super theCurrentMethod]`. It's not. The `super` keyword keeps the receiver (`self`) the same, but just skips over the current class when resolving that message to a particular implementation. But when you explicitly send a message to `[self superclass]`, the superclass itself is the receiver.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, it was so obvious :)