# How to call a method of super.super?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I want to call a method of super class of a super class, without breaking the inheritance chain. Something like this:

```
+(id) alloc 
{
    return [super.super alloc];
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Do not confuse with behavior offering by `superclass` method, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085349/aclass-superclass-superclass-construction).

---

**UPD:**

A few words about `super` and `superclass` differences.

Lets say, we have `AClass` and `SuperAClass`. As follows from their names `AClass` inherits `SuperAClass`. Each of them has an implementation of a method `-(void) foo;`

`AClass` implements **one of** the following class methods:

**1. superclass:**

```
+(id) alloc {
    return [[self superclass] alloc];
}
```

**2. super:**

```
+(id) alloc {
    return [super alloc];
}
```

Now, suppose these 2 lines of code:

```
AClass *AClassInstance = [AClass alloc];
[AClassInstance foo];
```

In first case (using superclass), `SuperAClass`'s `foo` method will be called.
For the second case (using super), `AClass`'s `foo` method will be called.

Comment: #1: I believe you’ve mixed the title of your examples (1. super, 2. superclass) with the actual code.

Comment: #2: `AClass AClassInstance = [AClass alloc];` is not valid since Objective-C objects must live on the heap and hence require pointers in their declarations.

Comment: #3: You cannot send `[AClassInstance foo]` since `AClassInstance` is not a class and `+foo` is a class method.

Comment: #4: `alloc` is a class method, hence `+ (id)alloc`

Comment: If might help if you describe textually what behaviour you’re expecting.

Comment: Thanks for #1 #2 #3 #4 remarks, fixed. The behavior is simple, I would like to access `foo` of AClass instead of their SuperAClass (or questionable SuperSuperAClass).

Comment: You should move `solution` into an answer (out of the question area.)  (a) it's difficult to find/read and (b) allows people to vote on the solution.  Also more *The StackOverflow Way*  :)

Comment: @Olie done. BTW, when this question has been asked, answering to your own questions was not really in _StackOverflow Way_ ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your particular example, `+superclass` is actually the way to go:

```
+ (id)someClassMethod {
    return [[[self superclass] superclass] someClassMethod];
}
```

since it is a class method, hence `self` refers to the class object where `+someClassMethod` is being defined.

On the other hand, things get a tad more complicated in instance methods. One solution is to get a pointer to the method implementation in the supersuper (grandparent) class. For instance:

```
- (id)someInstanceMethod {
    Class granny = [[self superclass] superclass];
    IMP grannyImp = class_getMethodImplementation(granny, _cmd);
    return grannyImp(self, _cmd);
}
```

Similarly to the class method example, `+superclass` is sent twice to obtain the supersuperclass. `IMP` is a pointer to a method, and we obtain an IMP to the method whose name is the same as the current one (`-someInstaceMethod`) but pointing to the implementation in the supersuperclass, and then call it. Note that you’d need to tweak this in case there are method arguments and return values different from `id`.

Comment: The name `grannyImp` made me smile.

Comment: Unfortunately, `superclass` case is not what I want to use. Please, consider my question update.

Comment: thanks for great runtime tips, your answer is so close! The problem is finally solved, see updated question.

Comment: don't forget to `#include <objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: I tried this but got an EXC_BAD ACCESS at the method call in granny. I didn't actually return grannyImp(self, _cmd), just called it. That could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Bavarious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102847/how-to-call-a-method-of-super-super/5103286#5103286) who inspired me to involve some runtime staff.

Briefly, the desired hypothetical line:

```
return [super.super alloc];
```

can be transformed in this "real" one:

```
return method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod([[self superclass] superclass], _cmd))([self class], _cmd);
```

To make it relatively more clear, it can be expanded as follow:

```
Method grannyMethod = class_getClassMethod([[self superclass] superclass], _cmd);
IMP grannyImp = method_getImplementation(grannyMethod);
return grannyImp([self class], _cmd);
```