# Inheritance of only certain superclass implementations

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I ran into a problem with inheritance in a current iOS project:

The current inheritance structure looks like this (Simple representation):

```
    CommonWidget
        AWidget
            AWidgetDetailsView
        BWidget
            BWidgetDetailsView
        RoundWidget
            RoundWidgetDetailsView
```

`CommonWidget` declares and implements several layout methods for shadows, background, icons, buttons, etc. In the `A...` & `B...` classes, this code is reused, since the views look similar, but have different models. So far no problem \o/

The Designer now introduced a new kind Widget, the `RoundWidget`, that looks somewhat different, yet the `RoundWidgetDetailsView` looks like the other `_DetailsViews`.

This leads to the problem: `RoundWidget` overwrites the layout methods of `CommonWidget` which means that `RoundWidgetDetailsView` obviously uses those methods as well.

More or less, it comes down to an alternative to the accepted answer of this question:

[How to call a method of super.super?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102847/how-to-call-a-method-of-super-super)

Or, simply put, any suggestions on how to change the inheritance structure to avoid running into the same problem in the future?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Tobias

Comment: From your description I don't see any need to use the runtime. Just override the methods you need to override and call super if appropriate or if u use the parent class implementation as is , don't override the method at all.

Comment: Another way to handle is to change the class hierarchy to have for example a super class that implements all common methods then intermediate siblings that diverge in some way.

Comment: Just extract the methods outside of your classes. This happens everytime when you start making subclasses only to share implementation.