# Swift Inheritance: Super's Super

Tags: swift, inheritance

Supposing to have this three classes with this simply hierarchy:

```
class A {
    func foo() {
       print("A")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func foo() {
       super.foo()
       print("B")
    }
}

class C: B {
    override func foo() {
       // *******
       print("C")
    }
}
```

In class C, in overrided method **foo** I want to call a method `foo:` is it possible?

In C++ this can be achieved with `C->A::foo()`, but how do I do this in Swift?

Comment: `super.super.foo()`.

Comment: I tried `super.super.foo()` and it doesn't compile

Comment: Was the first thing I tried and did not work, definitely!

Comment: This is intentionally hidden. There is absolutely no need for `C` to access the original declaration of `A` in any sane object architecture

Comment: By thy way, the reason why in C++ this is possible is due to multiple inheritance. `super` is not enough in C++ so they had to allow to specify the base class explicitly. Using implementation that has been overriden by superclass seems like a very very bad idea.

Comment: Additionally, the Objective-C runtime (and Swift) does not support multiple inheritance.  Use protocols, expose an accessor, or get an opaque pointer to the superclass's superclass and fire the selector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`super.foo()` should be sufficient, since B prints `"B"` and calls `super` to print `"A"`.

```
class C: B {
    override func foo() {
        super.foo()
        print("C")
    }
}
```

```
let c = C()
c.foo()
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

If you want to intentionally expose `A`'s `foo()` from `B`, you need to create a new accessor:

```
class B: A {
    override func foo() {
        super.foo()
        print("B")
    }

    func exposeFoo() {
        super.foo()
    }
}

class C: B {
    override func foo() {
        super.exposeFoo()
        print("C")
    }
}
```

Or, use `NSObject` and the power of the Objective-C runtime:

```
class A: NSObject { // make sure your base class inherits from NSObject
    func foo() {
        print("A")
    }
}

// ...

class C: B {
    override func foo() {

        guard let superSuper = self.superclass?.superclass() else {
            return; // no super super
        }

        let fooImp = class_getMethodImplementation(superSuper, "foo")

        typealias MyCFunction = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector) -> Void
        let curriedImplementation = unsafeBitCast(fooImp, MyCFunction.self)
        curriedImplementation(self, selector) // prints A
    }
}
```

Comment: I already think to adopt this way, but I can explain why I can't call A::foo explicitly

Comment: @Velthune read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5102847/2415822).  If you can inherit from `NSObject` you can access the object's `superclass` and use the Objective-C runtime to create a `COpaquePointer` to the superclass's superclass and fire A's `foo` selector.  Multiple inheritance is not supported.

Comment: Notable, very notable! Thanks for the link and tips!