# Is it possible to specify self to methods in Swift?

Tags: swift, oop

If you have several compatible objects:

```
class Animal { ... }

class Mammal: Animal { ... }

class Platypus: Mammal {

  override func walk() {
    if something {
      Animal.walk(self: self)
    } else {
      Mammal.walk(self: self)
    }
  }
}
```

And, let's say, you want to call one super's method in one case, but the other super's method in the other, would it be possible to pass `self` explicitly as an argument?

The question is provoked by the following hint in Xcode.
[image: Xcode suggests methods when you type dot after a class name]

What does this suggestion really mean?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870781/swift-inheritance-supers-super) useful to your case?

Comment: @AhmadF, almost — I'd like to know where does the Xcode suggestion comes from.

Comment: @Schmo It's because [instance methods are curried functions](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sulthan's answer correctly shows how you can pass `self` to superclass functions. I just want to explain and visualize a little bit what that XCode suggestion is.

If you look closely (or try it out) you'll see that calling the function in the suggested way will not actually *call* it but rather return it.

Since `f` is an instance method it can only be called on an instance. If you call `X.f(...)` you have to pass an instance of `X` to be able to call `f` on that instance.

So for example, if you have:

```
class X {
    var description: String

    init(desc: String) {
        description = desc
    }

    func f() {
        print(description)
    }
}
```

and then you say

```
var function = X.f(X(desc: "A specific description"))  // passing an instance of X
```

then you can call the function with

```
function()
```

and you will see

```
A specific description
```

*alternatively you could have also immediately called the function with:*

```
X.f(X(desc: "A specific description"))()
```

Or:

```
X(desc: "A specific description").f()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is completely possible, if you use *static* dispatch

```
class Animal {
   static func walk(_ animal: Animal) {
     ...
   }
}

class Mammal : Animal {
   static func walk(_ mammal: Mammal) {
     ...
   }
}
```

However, it is very strange from architecture point of view. It breaks polymorphism.

Note that you won't be able to call `animal.walk()` on an instance anymore. You would have to also define a separate instance method.

Comment: Agreed, but it's still unclear for me what does Xcode tries to say.

Comment: @Schmo Technically, an instance method is a method with one parameter - `self`. You can then use that method as a function with one parameter.